# Select From Where Not Exists query

Tags: mysql, sql

Memberships table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Consultant_Memberships` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `membership_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

Memberships_List table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Consultant_Memberships_List` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `consultant_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `membership_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Within the Memberships table, there is a list of 'Societies' which the member can become a part of. On selection, this is then added to the 'Memberships_List' in the form of:

1. id - Auto increment
2. consultant_id - The unique ID of the user who's added the societies
3. membership_id - Refers to the 'id' from the memberships table.

I want to be able to show in a drop down list **only** the memberships which the user hasn't chosen yet. So far I've got:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT `Consultant_Memberships.`id`, `Consultant_Memberships`.`title` `FROM `Consultant_Memberships 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT `Consultant_Memberships`.`id`, `Consultant_Memberships`.`title` 
WHERE `Consultant_Memberships`.`id` = $user_id)");
```

I'm currently getting this error, and also unsure if this is the correct query:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `Consultant_Memberships_List`.`id` = )' at line 1' in /Users/Sites/pages/medical.php:72
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/Sites/pages/medical.php(72): PDO->query('SELECT `Consult...')
#1 /Users/Sites/index.php(18): include('/Users/Site...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /Users/Sites/pages/medical.php on line 72
```

Comment: 'FROM' is missing in the `NOT EXISTS` subquery.

Answer (score 1):

`FROM` is missing in the `NOT EXISTS` subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `Consultant_Memberships.`id`, `Consultant_Memberships`.`title` `FROM `Consultant_Memberships 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT `Consultant_Memberships`.`id`, `Consultant_Memberships`.`title` 
WHERE `Consultant_Memberships`.`id` = $user_id)
```

you have a wrong syntax try something like this i am not writing exect query but checked in sql fiddle and thats wrond

```
SELECT Consultant_Memberships.id, Consultant_Memberships.title FROM Consultant_Memberships 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Consultant_Memberships.id, Consultant_Memberships.title from Consultant_Memberships
WHERE Consultant_Memberships.id = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Always watch to the left from the highlighted query part. WHERE in your case

```
SELECT `Consultant_Memberships.`id`, `Consultant_Memberships`.`title`
`FROM <--- extra backtick
`Consultant_Memberships <--- unclosed backtick
```

by the way, do not overuse backticks. most of your fields require them not

...and you have your query totally screwed as it seems
As far as I understood your question, it have to be

```
SELECT cm.id, title 
FROM Consultant_Memberships cm LEFT JOIN Consultant_Memberships_List
ON cm.id=membership_id WHERE membership_id IS NULL
```

Please note that your question has nothing to do with PDO.
it's clear SQL query question.

Comment: I've added it to an SQL Fiddle to make it easier to understand, I have no idea where the error is unfortunately: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c25e/4

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this one:

```
SELECT a.id, a.title 
FROM Consultant_Memberships a, Consultant_Memberships_List b
WHERE a.id <> b.consultant_id
```

The reason you are getting syntax error because if you see your subquery you will find out that you are not specifying any table in it.

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT `Consultant_Memberships`.`id`, `Consultant_Memberships`.`title` 
WHERE `Consultant_Memberships`.`id` = $user_id)
```

If you need more help, please let us know...

Regards...
Mr.777

Comment: Hi @Mr.777, The query shown above unfortunately matches the Primary Key within the Consultant_Memberships with the consultant_id within the Consultant_Memberships_List. I've tweaked the query but unfortunately I still get an error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3c25e/11

Comment: Run this query without "" please..... I just done this and it ran successfully without any error....